# apache ExpiresDefault - just doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

we all know that setting expire date for static files is very useful and the way i found to do so is through the `ExpiresDefault` property in a .htaccess file but it just doesn't work. I am using YSlow and page_speed to test the HTTP response, but it just keep on telling me that I need to set an expire date for my JS, CSS and images to speed up my application.

I tried to test `ExpiresDefault` "access plus 1 year" , locally ( apache server ) and on the web ( hostgator reseller account. if I have any options to make use of !?! ) but it just doesn't work. And it also doesn't return 500 error.

I feel like I am missing the main point or doing it wrong. How the whole thing should be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, identified [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) is compiled inside your apache.

Try

```
PATH_TO_YOUR/httpd -M | sort /* <-- look for expires_module*/
```

And your apache configuration should be like

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

And always restart apache after configuration changed

Comment: thanks, it's works :) , but is there a way to activate thid mod on my remote server .. like i said i have a reseller account from host gator >>>> Thanks again

Comment: @Dewan159 - That's depend on your remote server ... which you have to check with your service provider.